# Elastic Stack - Unable to run logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I am new to ELK and I am unable to run Logstash.
I am trying with :

```
cd /usr/share/logstash/bin
logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'
```

Its coming "logstash command not found" .

The question is solved by ading `./` before logstash. Thanks for @val.
But now I am facing another issue. after running the above command I am not getting any output. Please refer to the screenshot. The output should be  `2013-11-21T01:22:14.405+0000 0.0.0.0 hello`
But I am not getting anything. Can anyone please help
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `./logstash` as `logstash` is most probably not on the PATH:

```
   cd /usr/share/logstash/bin
   ./logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'
   ^^
   ||
add this
```

Comment: Hi, what's this 
 ^^
   ||
Can you please explain ?

Comment: Two ascii arrows to show where the changes need to be made ;-)

Comment: My bad, its working now. Thanks, But after running    
`./logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }' `
I am typing hello. The output should be 
`2013-11-21T01:22:14.405+0000 0.0.0.0 hello `
But I am not getting anything. Can you please help ? I have atatched the screenshot in the question for refrence

Comment: Logstash can take time to start, and judging by your screenshot it hasn't fully started when you type hello.

Comment: yes, you're right. I've asked that in another question. Can you please look ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64199452/logstash-not-showing-any-output-in-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment113526012_64199452

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222508/discussion-between-vatsal-agarwal-and-val).

Comment: Yes. I am closing this. can you just answer my other quesion ?