# Logstash not showing any output in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am learning ELK and I am stucked in logstash.
My Elastic and Kibana are running.
But when I am trying ot Logstash, my pipeline is not getting started.
I am running following commands

```
  cd /usr/share/logstash/bin
  ./logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'
```

In Elastic Documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/first-event.html) they've written :

After starting Logstash, wait until you see "**Pipeline main started**" and then enter hello world at the command prompt.

But when I am running the above commands, I am not getting any output saying "**Pipeline main started**" .
The putput I 'm getting is :

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
FATAL] 2020-10-04 20:16:56.659 [main] runner - An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<ArgumentError: Path "/usr/share/logstash/data" must be a writable directory. It is not writable.>, 
[ERROR] 2020-10-04 20:16:56.715 [main] Logstash - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

After this error I tried changing the permisions by following :

```
 $ chown -R logstash.logstash /usr/share/logstash
    $ chmod 777 /usr/share/logstash/data
```

I'm getting below error

```
chown: changing ownership of '/var/log/logstash': Operation not permitted
```

can anyone please help me out ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possibly `sudo chown ...` . Gnerally not a good idea to 777 dirs, see if it 755 works. If you get a futher error message when  using `sudo`, then  you'll have to research that separately, and I wouldn't be a good person to help you debug it. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are running logstash instance as logstash user then you can change the ownership of logstash directory

```
sudo chown -R logstash.logstash /usr/share/logstash
```

or else you can run logstash with sudo privilege

```
sudo ./logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'
```